# How can I parse a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have string looking like this:

```
01
02
03
99
```

I'd like to parse these to make them into strings like:

```
 1. 2. 3. 99. etc.
```

The numbers are a maximum of 2 characters. Also I have to parse some more numbers later in the source string so I would like to learn the substring equivalent in javascript. Can someone give me advice on how I can do. Previously I had been doing it in C# with the following:

```
int.Parse(RowKey.Substring(0, 2)).ToString() + "."
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, `parseInt` of course.

```
// Add 2 until end of string
var originalA = "01020399";
for (var i = 0; i < originalA.length; i += 2)
{
  document.write(parseInt(originalA.substr(i, 2), 10) + ". ");
}

// Split on carriage returns
var originalB = "01\n02\n03\n99";
var strArrayB = originalB.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < strArrayB.length; i++)
{
  document.write(parseInt(strArrayB[i], 10) + ". ");
}

// Replace the leading zero with regular expressions
var originalC = "01\n02\n03\n99";
var strArrayC = originalC.split("\n");
var regExpC = /^0/;
for (var i = 0; i < strArrayC.length; i++)
{
  document.write(strArrayC[i].replace(regExpC, "") + ". ");
}
```

The other notes are that JavaScript is weakly typed, so `"a" + 1` returns `"a1"`. Additionally, for substrings you can choose between `substring(start, end)` and `substr(start, length)`. If you're just trying to pull a single character, `"abcdefg"[2]` will return `"c"` (zero-based index, so 2 means the third character). You usually won't have to worry about type-casting when it comes to simple numbers or letters.

http://jsfiddle.net/mbwt4/3/

Comment: But I need a string as I will add the "." character. How can I convert the above to a string?

Comment: JavaScript is weakly typed, so you can just use `+` to combine a string and a number. If you're uncomfortable with that, substitute `parseInt(test.substr(i, 2)).toString()` above.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I didn't realize it was weekly typed. Works great. I'll accept.

Comment: You need to have the base 10 on parseInt or the leading zero is going to cause problems. parseInt( num, 10);

Comment: @epascarello True, forgot about that. I've updated the code to reflect that. `parseInt` evaluates strings beginning with "0" in octal, so `parseInt("07")` returns `7` but `parseInt("08")` and `parseInt("09")` return `0`.

Answer (score 1):

use `parseInt` function.

parseInt(09)  //this will give you 9

```
var myString = parseInt("09").toString()+". "+parseInt("08").toString();
```

Comment: Later on I will need to get the value of the 4th and 5th characters in my string and do the same. Is there a substring kind of function in javascript ?

Comment: @TonyG - yes there is a [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) in javascript.

Comment: Thank you but I get this error message: function toString() { [native code] }

Comment: @TonyG- oops sorry, I missed braces ()

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = parseFloat('0099');
```

- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dtsWV/)

Comment: Will this give me something looking like "99." from the input?

Comment: Try: `var number = parseFloat('0099');`

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '01\n02\n03\n99';
array = string.split('\n');
string2 = '';
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = parseInt(array[i]);
    string2 += array[i] + '. ';
}
document.write(string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring in JavaScript works like this:

```
string.substring(from, to);
```

where `from` is inclusive and `to` is exclusive.  You can also use slice:

```
string.slice(from, to)
```

where `from` is inclusive and `to` is exclusive.  The difference between slice and substring is with slice you can specify negative numbers.  For example, `from = -1` indicates the last character.  `from(-1, -3)` would give you the last 2 characters of the string.

With both methods if you don't specify end then you will get all the characters to the end.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Ii they are always 2 digits how about;

```
var s = "01020399";
var result = []
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i+=2)
    result.push(parseInt(s.substr(i, 2), 10) + ".")

alert( result[2] )        // 3.
alert( result.join(" ") ) // 1. 2. 3. 99.
```